# Pyspark flatten embedded structs all into same level

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, flatten

Is there an easy way to make something like the top to the bottom picture where all columns are next to each other in an unnested way, same level?
[image: rk]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `source` struct by adding fields from the inner struct. Something like this:

```
# get all fields of source struct except the inner struct e_struct
source_cols = [col(f"source.{c}") for c in df.select(col("source.*")).columns if c != "e_struct"]

# get all fields of the inner struct e_struct
e_struct_cols = [col(f"source.e_struct.{c}") for c in df.select(col("source.e_struct.*")).columns]

# combine them
new_struct_cols = source_cols + e_struct_cols

# update source column
df = df.withColumn("source", struct(*new_struct_cols))
```